# Why sometimes Atlas shows different IP address than https://check.torproject.org?

Tags: exit-relays, atlas, torcheck

Once in a while [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) shows different IP address than https://check.torproject.org . An example is illustrated below:

> *check.torproject.org*  shows: Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
>
> Your IP address appears to be: 161.53.74.122

While Atlas shows:

> **Details for: UVic1100**
>   **General** Overall information on the Tor relay
>   **Configuration**
>
> **Nickname**
>        UVic1100
>      **OR Addresses**
>          142.104.68.93:443
>      **Contact**
>          undefined
>      **Dir Address**
>      **Advertised Bandwidth**
>          73.71 KB/s

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Check.tp.o shows the IP address you use at the moment. But at which point comes Atlas into play? Maybe you could explain it a bit more in detail.

Comment: Dear Jens, Simultaneously, or maybe I should say as soon as check.tp.o page appears, there is an Atlas hyperlink on that page which as a routine matter, I click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actively discussed in the [bug report #10499](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10499). It seems there is a bug in TorDNSEL. It might be a good idea to follow the report. So you get updates on the issue. I'll also try to update to answer if there is a solution.